# After upgrading to 16.04 keyboard and mouse lock up at random times

Tags: drivers, nvidia, keyboard, mouse, lockup

After upgrading to 16.04 (from 14.04) keyboard and mouse lock up at random times, and then the only thing that I can do is to manually power cycle the machine.
My machine is an older ACER with dual core i5 and NIVIDIA graphics.
Linux is the only OS on the machine.

This problem has made Ubuntu completely unusable for me. Although I have seen questions virtually identical to mine, since none of the replies provide workable verified solutions, I decided to post this in the hope that folks with fresh ideas would see it and help me out.

Comment: Ubuntu really dropped the ball releasing 16.04 with this bug not discovered.

Comment: I reinstalled ubuntu 16.04 but left out any third party software. This seems to have improved things. The mouse (and only the mouse) locked up once after an autologout.

Comment: Having made the following change to /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
seems to have solved the problem.
Followed by updating grub of course.

Comment: This time there was a keyboard lock up only, I could move the mouse but couldn't do anything with it like clicking the shutdown icon.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some issues with 16.04 myself and it all seems to stem from Nvidia. Please check out the numerous links contained with in this Ask Ubuntu post:

[Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

Comment: @user169954, If one of those links in particular helps will you please reply and paste the link here? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Jodamo117, but when the lock up happens. It REALLY locks up, I cannot get the TTY terminal cntrl+alt+F1 or reboot cntrl+alt+del or anything at all! And yes I agree with your diagnosis that it all stems from NIVIDIA. Nevertheless, before upgrading to 16.04 I had a perfectly properly functioning machine with exactly the same hardware.

Comment: I'm having to run Ubuntu thru a VM on my ASUS that has an Nividia.

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 (Good thing I keep my data on my NAS), but this time I declined the offer of installing 3rd party software for various devices. No lock up yet.